# Opening Play Store App within PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

I have designed a hybrid mobile application and there are two versions.  To direct users to another version, I have included this inside the HTML5 source

```
    <a href="market://details?id=com.kabam.ff7">

        <img id=offtomarket alt="Get it on Google Play"
            src="./img/android_app.png" />

    </a>
```

The image is perfectly displayed but it is not opening the play store app on my Android device.  Why is it?

com.kabam.ff7 is an example for now.

I also tried this approach

```
$("#offtomarket").click(    

 function(e) {  window.open('market://details?id=com.kabam.ff7'); 
                alert("offtomarketclicked"); 
              }               );
```

And it still did not work.  I do see the alert window.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace this:

```
window.open('market://details?id=com.kabam.ff7');
```

With this:

```
window.location.replace('market://details?id=com.kabam.ff7');
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution

install this plugin

https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market

CLI -

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market
```

And then in your JavaScript

```
cordova.plugins.market.open('com.kabam.ff7');
```

If you use jQuery and have a button with ID called mybutton

```
$("#mybutton").click(   function(e) {       

cordova.plugins.market.open('com.kabam.ff7');   } );
```

And include the following CSS in your CSS to make the badge look perfect

```
img
{
    width  : 100%;
    height : auto
}
```